# How to dynamically create columns in a datagridview and assign titles to it and its rows?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am using a datagridview for which I am not using any datasource. I want to dynamically allocate values to it. Create my own selected number of columns and rows and name them.
Plus I want to add images to cells instead of data .

As for changing columns text we can use

`grid.Columns[0].HeaderText = "First Column";`

How to change use it for labeling rows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `HeaderCell.Value` for the row:

```
    DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
    dgv.Columns.Add("Foo", "Foo Text");
    dgv.Rows.Add();
    dgv.Rows[0].HeaderCell.Value = "Row Text";

    Form form = new Form();
    form.Controls.Add(dgv);
    Application.Run(form);
```

Comment: its good but how to use images in cells instead of strings?
Plz help

Comment: There is an example here that shows using CellPainting for this; I haven't tested it, though: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/17a65aed-8796-408e-98e4-92a82999df13